# Percentages don't round up when using percent(accuracy = 3L) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a bar chart with percentage labels. I wanted to round the numbers to one decimal place, but for some reasons it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is an example with the first 50 out of 2400 rows:

```
structure(c(1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 
1L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Economic situation", "Corruption", 
"Democracy", "Internal stability and security", "Foreign interference", 
"Religious extremism", "Fighting terrorism", "Public services", 
"Security", "Political/party issues", "Others", "Don't know"), class = "factor")
```

I used this code getting this graph:

```
lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(challenge)) %>%
  count(challenge) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(challenge, prop), y = prop, fill = prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop, suffix = "")),
            position=position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.4, hjust = -0.1, size = 5) +
  labs(title = "What  is the most  important  challenge facing Lebanon today?", 
       x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 25),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

If I specify with `geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop, suffix = "", accuracy = 3L))` it rounds up to full numbers without any decimal place. I'm quite sure that there might be a small mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Greetings

Comment: The `accuracy` argument works like so : 1 = no decimal place, .1 = one decimal place, .01 = 2 decimal places, .... i.e. you give the pattern on how the result should look like or as the docs say "A number to round to. Use (e.g.) 0.01 to show 2 decimal places of precision."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you provide does not reproduce your problem, because the sample is too small.
Use `accuracy = 0.1`, this should solve it. Also minor edit with empty axis labels `axis.title = element_blank()`...

```r
lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(challenge)) %>%
  count(challenge) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(challenge, prop), y = prop, fill = prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop, suffix = "", accuracy = 0.1)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.4, hjust = -0.1, size = 5) +
  labs(title = "What  is the most  important  challenge facing Lebanon today?") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 25),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip()
```